# ¿Cómo capturar el tamaño de la pantalla en Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Quiero implementar el < mat-tab-group > de Angular material. Me interesa obtener el tamaño de pantalla para poder cambiar el valor de su atributo mat-align-tabs="center". En pantallas pequeñas se use el "center" y en pantallas MD en adelante usar el "end".

Código HTML sin tocar

```html
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="center">
  <mat-tab label="Inicio">
    <app-inicio></app-inicio>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Explorar">
    <app-explorar></app-explorar>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Cuentas">
    <app-cuentas></app-cuentas>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Código HTML de Módificado

```html
<mat-tab-group attr.mat-align-tabs="{{posicion}}">
  <mat-tab label="Inicio">
    <app-inicio></app-inicio>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Explorar">
    <app-explorar></app-explorar>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Cuentas">
    <app-cuentas></app-cuentas>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Código TS

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  public posicion: string;

  constructor() {
    this.posicion = 'center';
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

La variable "posicion" es la que quiero cambiar su valor dependiendo el tamaño de pantalla.

Comment: No se si te sirva en angular, estimo que si, para obtener alto y ancho usa window.innerWidth y window.innerHeight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tienes dos Opciones. La primera es usar el `@media` de tu css/scss:

En la primera solucion dentro de tus archivos css/scss

```
.mat-align-tabs { align: end} 

 @media (max-width:991.98px) { 
    .mat-align-tabs { align: center } 
 }
```

La segunda y recomendada por Angular es usar el `BreakpointObserver`:

```
 import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
  .
  .
  .
export class exmapleBreakpoint {

 public sizeDisplay: string = 'phone' || 'web';

 constructor(
  public breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver
 ){
    this.mediaQuery();
 }
  .
  .
  .
  public mediaQuery() {

    this.breakpointObserver
    .observe(Breakpoints.Small)
    .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
      if (state.matches) {
      //AQUI SERA TRUE SOLO SI ESTA EN RESOLUCION DE CELULAR
      this.sizeDisplay = 'phone';
    }
  });

  this.breakpointObserver
  .observe(Breakpoints.Web)
  .subscribe((state: BreakpointState) => {
    if (state.matches) {
      //AQUI SERA TRUE SOLO SI ES RESOLUCION PARA WEB
      this.sizeDisplay = 'web';
    }
  });
 }

}
```

Aquí creas una variable `public sizeDisplay: string = 'phone' || 'web'` y usando el `BreakpointObserver` obtienes un observable que siempre te dirá el valor actual de la pantalla y lo seteas a la variable. Posee diferentes configuraciones, trae valores preestablecidos (Web - Small...), pero tambien puedes configurar respuestas especificas para una resolucion unica.

Lee su docu y entenderás mucho mas: https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview

Éxitos.